# Incorrect dynamic field type for Droptree

Tags: content-search, solr

Background: Sitecore 9, Solr 6.6.1

I have got a strange issue with incorrect resolution of field type by SOLR during item indexing.

I read the following article about resolution a field names:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/using_solr_field_name_resolution

There are two separate stages of resolution:

- Field name resolution during indexing
- Field name resolution during search

**Field name resolution during indexing**

As it is described in the documentation, Sitecore uses the `AddFieldByFieldTypeName` and `AddTypeMatch` sections of the configuration file for maping Sitecore field types to dynamic field types.

The default definition of `AddFieldByFieldTypeName` section of `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`:

```
<fieldTypes hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldTypeName">            
   <!-- Skipped some rows as it doesn't matter in my case -->       
   <fieldType fieldTypeName="checklist|multilist|treelist|tree list|treelistex|tree list|multilist with search|treelist with search" returnType="stringCollection" />
   <fieldType fieldTypeName="name lookup value list|name value list" returnType="stringCollection" />
   <fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree" returnType="stringCollection" />
</fieldTypes>
```

I have a field **ProductModel** with **Droptree** type in Sitecore. As we can see it has to be associated with `stringCollection` type.

Let's look further. The default definition of `AddTypeMatch` section:

```
<typeMatches hint="raw:AddTypeMatch">
    <typeMatch typeName="guidCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="textCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_txm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="stringCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="intCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_im" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="guid" type="System.Guid" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="id" type="Sitecore.Data.ID, Sitecore.Kernel" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="shortid" type="Sitecore.Data.ShortID, Sitecore.Kernel" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="string" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_s" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="text" type="System.String" fieldNameFormat="{0}_t" cultureFormat="_{1}" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="int" type="System.Int32" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="bool" type="System.Boolean" fieldNameFormat="{0}_b" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="datetime" type="System.DateTime" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tdt" format="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.FFF'Z'" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="long" type="System.Int64" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tl" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="float" type="System.Single" fieldNameFormat="{0}_tf" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="double" type="System.Double" fieldNameFormat="{0}_td" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="stringArray" type="System.String[]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="intArray" type="System.Int32[]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_im" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="datetimeArray" type="System.DateTime[]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="datetimeCollection" type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime]" fieldNameFormat="{0}_dtm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
    <typeMatch typeName="coordinate" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data.Coordinate, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Data" fieldNameFormat="{0}_rpt" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider" />
</typeMatches>
```

We can see that the field which was associated with type `stringCollection` should have the `fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm"` format.

BUT, when I look in the index, the field has `"{0}_s"` format and looks like:

```
"productmodel_s":"b1550b9524e64d03a7f2b472dad5cd53"
```

**This is the key point in my problem!** because when I try to build facet based on this field:

```
ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("sitecore_web_index").CreateSearchContext().GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().FacetOn(item => item["productmodel"]).GetResults();
```

my query looks like:

```
Solr Query - ?q=(*:*)&rows=2147483647&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_web_index)&fq=(_language:(en*))&facet=true&facet.field=productmodel_sm&f.productmodel_sm.facet.mincount=0&wt=xml
```

ProductModel field has `productmodel_sm` format and definitely Solr can't find this field and I don't get any facets.

**The question is why the field name resolution is defined wrong during indexing?**

Comment: _s suffix looks correct for Droptree field value as it is actually only one ID. I would check 'droptree' configuration on showconfig.aspx page

Comment: @Daniil probably yes, but in accordance with a process of the field name resolution which described on the documentation, it should be _sm. Anyway, the name should be the same both during indexing and the search time.

Comment: Does having more than one value for the `ProductModel` change the type it gets indexed as (`*_sm` instead of `*_s`)? I am just wondering if this is a bug where the converter is misinterpreting the type rather than taking it from the defined Field Type of the Sitecore field.

Comment: @vandsh I know about issues that we can get if we have a few fields with the same name. It is the first what I checked and I don't have another filed with the `ProductModel` name.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich Sorry maybe I was unclear, I didn't mean fields named the same, I meant if you were to actually put multiple values into your `Product Model` field (rather than a single value in your example).  My wild guess is that the field converter logic is picking it up a as a single string rather than multi-valued.

Comment: @vandsh the ProductModel field has the Droptree type. I can’t select more than one value.

Comment: @ArtsemPrashkovich you should be able to check the `Raw Values` and drop a pipe and another guid in order to test.  My hope was to see that providing multiple values would change the indexed type to `*_sm` thus indicting that the converter is inferring type rather than taking what is defined in the `DefaultIndexConfiguration` (`droptree->stringCollection`)

Comment: Could you make available the whole of the Solr Default Index Configuration and the configuration pertaining to the index in question?

Comment: @RichardHauer I use the default Sitecore 9 search configurations: `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` and `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config`
and I didn't change anything there.

Comment: @vandsh I've tried to set multiple values. The field type was not changed. It is still  `productmodel_s`.

Comment: I encounter a similar issue between text and string.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just ran into the same issue with a `Droplink`. This definitely seems like a bug.

My guess is that the indexing type is actually being set based on the return type of field reader associated with the field type:

```xml
<fieldReader fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree|reference" 
    fieldReaderType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.FieldReaders.LookupFieldReader, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
```

I was able to work around the issue by patching the `returnType` to `string`:

```xml
<fieldType fieldTypeName="droplink|droptree|grouped droplink|tree" returnType="string" />
```

Comment: Had exact same problem. Definitely a bug or just a fail on Sitecore's part to get their default SOLR config correct. Can anyone think of a reason why it needs to be `string` and not `id`? All those fields ultimately contain links as guids so it seems like the right match. However maybe there are issues with blanks? Who knows, `string` works, though.

Answer (score 0):

In your mapping model, try to add `[TypeConverter]` attribute like this:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldIDValueConverter))]
public virtual ID YourProperty { get; set; }
```

With that it will correctly map `stringCollection` to your model.